# Extract a string between a particular string pattern

Tags: sed

I have an *ethereum*  log file from which I would like to extract transaction hash located between a particular string *Tx(0x* and *)* and there are lot of lines before and after it.

**Input File**

```
I0623 10:56:00.025283 miner/worker.go:516] commit new work on block 1903 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 621.171µs
I0623 10:56:00.025349 miner/unconfirmed.go:105]   mined block #1897 [21f018be…] reached canonical chain
I0623 10:56:07.270041 rlp/encode.go:109] 02
I0623 10:56:07.270908 rlp/encode.go:109] 03
I0623 10:56:15.706523 internal/ethapi/api.go:1034] Debug message
I0623 10:56:15.738777 internal/ethapi/api.go:1052] Tx(0x22fb16e22be2123a161c887739d73ecca56a417ce176398da5a766067acb40ff) to (Debug message): 0x36c282bd92e0a8aece9886ac5e05d9432f3b6a29
I0623 10:56:15.739130 rlp/encode.go:109] 12
I0623 10:56:15.893529 internal/ethapi/api.go:1034] Debug message
I0623 10:56:15.896059 internal/ethapi/api.go:1052] Tx(0xa39474928ba5af3ef62950e0ce3b7a94f57eaf7fe9b7019d161de28f38d312c2) to (Debug message): 0x36c282bd92e0a8aece9886ac5e05d9432f3b6a29
I0623 10:56:15.896365 rlp/encode.go:109] 12
I0623 10:56:16.042498 internal/ethapi/api.go:1034] Debug message
I0623 10:56:16.044437 internal/ethapi/api.go:1052] Tx(0x953d94df1760f4b97377874a4cb3051927619e3cc29f38646c48913fb077d48e) to (Debug message): 0x36c282bd92e0a8aece9886ac5e05d9432f3b6a29
I0623 10:56:16.044604 rlp/encode.go:109] 12
I0623 10:56:16.156818 internal/ethapi/api.go:1034] Debug message
I0623 10:56:16.158712 internal/ethapi/api.go:1052] Tx(0x3feeda56a2c96663198c572685d574057cfa1ca92c9c0598e125d8d9cd3fc9f2) to (Debug message): 0x36c282bd92e0a8aece9886ac5e05d9432f3b6a29
I0623 10:56:16.159084 rlp/encode.go:109] 12
I0623 10:56:16.262574 internal/ethapi/api.go:1034] Debug message
I0623 10:56:16.264259 internal/ethapi/api.go:1052] Tx(0x12eaf5c4af1eb46a12d1bc642a59bf229e1ea7c1c941c1dfa3426e0b89f1a737) to (Debug message): 0x36c282bd92e0a8aece9886ac5e05d9432f3b6a29
I0623 10:56:16.264575 rlp/encode.go:109] 12
I0623 10:56:16.368707 internal/ethapi/api.go:1034] Debug message
I0623 10:56:16.370449 internal/ethapi/api.go:1052] Tx(0x3258bd0071968546584be0dfc63df130c3d71c6fcf41cf3caed3475c7c1d1a8e) to (Debug message): 0x36c282bd92e0a8aece9886ac5e05d9432f3b6a29
```

**Output File**

```
22fb16e22be2123a161c887739d73ecca56a417ce176398da5a766067acb40ff
a39474928ba5af3ef62950e0ce3b7a94f57eaf7fe9b7019d161de28f38d312c2
953d94df1760f4b97377874a4cb3051927619e3cc29f38646c48913fb077d48e
3feeda56a2c96663198c572685d574057cfa1ca92c9c0598e125d8d9cd3fc9f2
12eaf5c4af1eb46a12d1bc642a59bf229e1ea7c1c941c1dfa3426e0b89f1a737
3258bd0071968546584be0dfc63df130c3d71c6fcf41cf3caed3475c7c1d1a8e
```

Answer (score 0):

If only one Tx... per line:

```
sed -n 's/.*Tx(0x\(.*\)) to.*/\1/p' logfile > outfile
```

Option `-n` to supress output for lines without match

Comment: thanks a lot @farax but  this "grep -o '\Tx(.*) '  logMinter.log | sed  -e 's/Tx(0x//;s/) //' > transactionHash" is giving me the desired result

Comment: @VarunGupta I slightly changed the answer of farax to make it work and you don't need `grep` or pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `awk` with multiple delimiters:

```
awk -F 'Tx\\(0x|)' '/Tx/ {print $2}' <your_file>
```

Where:

- `-F 'Tx\\(0x|)'`: use delimiters **Tx(0x** and **)**
- `/Tx/`: only print lines containing **Tx**
- `{print $2}`: print second element